# Историческое значение местоимения КТО

Tags: история

Историки русского языка, вопрос к вам!

Недавно я задавала вопрос о том, почему местоимение «кто» в найденном мною предложении не согласуется со сказуемым в женском роде. Мне ответили, что «кто» (видимо, традиционно) согласуется именно с мужским родом за редкими исключениями. (Предложение звучало так: «Вы узнаете, кто из фавориток так и не смог ответить Павлу I взаимностью.»)

Так вот, мне интересно, откуда пошла эта традиция связывать обезличенное «кто» с мужским родом? Связано ли это с тем, что русский язык развивался в патриархальном обществе, в котором полноценной личностью считался именно мужчина, а не женщина?

Comment: Пример неудачен. Тем более, что ответы были даны убедительные. Здесь такое, к примеру, подошло бы — «Когда отец спросил, кто звонил, она сказала, что подружка из института» [Лев Дворецкий. Шакалы (2000)]

Answer (score 1):

Местоимение ***кто*** не имеет рода, а относится ко всем одушевлённым предметам мужского, женского и среднего рода.

*Кто?* — Кошка
*Кто?* — Кот
*Кто?* — Животное

Местоимение ***кто*** противопоставляется местоимению ***что***, относящемуся к неодушевлённым объектам.

В случае, когда пол одушевлённого предмета является неопределённым, используется мужской род.

Рассмотрим название книги:

> Животное против животного. Кто самый быстрый?
>
> [[my-shop.ru](https://my-shop.ru/shop/product/4374526.html)]

Заметьте: не ***кто самое быстрое***, а ***кто самый быстрый***.

Использование мужского рода по отношению к животному никак не связано с патриархальным обществом.

---

**А теперь подробнее:**

> Местоимение ***кто*** относится к одушевленным предметам (людям и
> животным); местоимение ***что*** — к неодушевленным предметам.
> ...
> **Местоимения *кто*, *что* не имеют форм грамматического рода и числа. Сказуемое при подлежащем *кто* ставится, как правило, в мужском роде
> единственного числа независимо от пола и числа лиц, о которых идет
> речь**, напр.: ***Кто** пришел? ***Кто*** из девушек это заявил? **Кто** из работниц
> сегодня заболел (болен)? Все, **кто** был свободен, уехали за город.
>  А
> если **кто** для меня ***непонятен***, так это моя бабушка, графиня Анна
> Федотовна.* Пушк., Пик. дама, I.
> ...
> [Грамматика русского языка. Том I Фонетика и морфология. В. В. Виноградов, Е. С. Истрина,  С. Г. Борхударов]

Поскольку местоимение ***кто*** не имеет формы грамматического рода, по отношению к нему используется мужской род.

> **Часто мужской род выступает как немаркированный элемент категории
> рода, выбираемый по умолчанию. Так, в русском языке местоимение кто —
> мужского рода (нельзя сказать *Кто пришла?)**, в романских языках, где
> есть различие родов во множественном числе, о множестве объектов
> женского и мужского рода говорится «они» в мужском роде (ils/eux,
> ellos); ср. **в русском языке *оба* о мужчине и женщине (*обе* только о двух
> женщинах)**.
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4)]

---

**А теперь об истории:**

Приведённый выше пример со словом «животное» говорит о том, что причина никак не в патриархальном обществе.

На мой взгляд, причина заключается в следующем.

Русский язык относится к индоевропейским языкам, т. е. имеет своим предком праиндоевропейский язык:

> It [Russian language] is a part of the Indo-European language family...
>
> Он [русский язык] является частью индоевропейской языковой семьи...
>
> [[Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language)]

> All Indo-European languages are descended from a single prehistoric
> language, reconstructed as Proto-Indo-European
>
> Все индоевропейские языки произошли от единого доисторического языка,
> реконструированного как праиндоевропейский.
>
> [[Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages)]

Предок русского языка, праиндоевропейский язык, вероятно, изначально имел два рода: одушевлённый и неодушевлённый.

> Late PIE had three genders, traditionally called masculine, feminine
> and neuter. ... Originally, there probably were only an animate
> (masculine/feminine) and an inanimate (neuter) gender. This view is
> supported by the existence of certain classes of Latin and Ancient
> Greek adjectives which inflect only for two sets of endings: one for
> masculine and feminine, the other for neuter. Further evidence comes
> from the Anatolian languages such as Hittite which exhibit only the
> animate and the neuter genders.
>
> Поздний праиндоевропейский язык имел три рода, традиционно называемых
> мужским, женским и средним... **Первоначально, вероятно,
> были только одушевленный (мужской/женский) и неодушевленный
> (средний) род**. Эта точка зрения поддерживается существованием
> определенных классов латинских и древнегреческих прилагательных,
> которые склоняются только для двух наборов окончаний: одно — для
> мужского и женского рода, другое — для среднего рода. Дальнейшие
> свидетельства поступают из анатолийских языков, таких как хеттский, в
> которых представлены только одушевленный и средний род.

Изначально было, скорей всего, два рода:

1. **род одушевлённых объектов**, от которого отпочковался женский род, а  сам род одушевлённых объектов стал сейчас мужским;
2. **род неодушевлённых объектов**, который превратился в средний.

Приведу отрывок из статьи «[Что такое грамматический род и откуда он взялся](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/nplus1/chto-takoe-grammaticheskii-rod-i-otkuda-on-vzialsia-5e34003b6711673ecbb12f80)» с сайта [zen.yandex.ru](https://zen.yandex.ru/):

> Дело в том, что русский и другие привычные нам языки с тремя родами не
> всегда были такими, как сейчас. Да и вообще: 8000 лет назад еще не
> было русского, английского, немецкого, латыни, санскрита и греческого,
> а был их общий язык-предок, который называется праиндоевропейским
> языком.
>
> И в этом языке **родов было не три, а два**; такое состояние сохранил
> хеттский язык, представитель вымершей языковой ветви, которая
> отделилась от индоевропейского первой. **Эти два рода можно назвать
> общим и средним, или активным и инактивным классом.**
>
> К активному классу относились слова, обозначающие живых существ,
> активные части человеческого тела: рука, нога, зуб, — а также все, что
> мыслится как живое: ветер, гроза, судьба и так далее. Все остальные
> существительные — инактивные: одежда, ярмо, слово и так далее.
>
> Однако затем начинает распространяться суффикс, который имеет значение
> «женщина» и звучит как -eh2- или -h2- (запись h2 обозначает один из
> трех особых h-образных согласных, которые были в праиндоевропейском
> языке).
>
> Это было слишком давно, так что мы не можем проследить все детали
> этого процесса, и ученые до сих пор спорят, откуда этот суффикс
> возник, но можно с уверенностью сказать, что когда слов с таким
> суффиксом стало много, он перенесся и на прилагательные, стоящие рядом
> с этими словами.
>
> **Именно так в праиндоевропейском языке и появился новый
> согласовательный класс: из общего рода выделился женский (вполне
> естественно, что часть общего рода, которая осталась после этого
> события, мы называем мужским родом).**
>
> **Из этого -eh2-, собственно говоря, и произошло наше окончание -а в
> словах типа жена, сестра, трава и в прилагательных типа жива, молода**...

**Заключение:**

Получается, что изначально, вероятно, было два рода, которые можно назвать одушевлённый и неодушевлённый.

От одушевлённого позже отпочковался женский род. А сам одушевлённый род стали называть  мужским родом; и хотя теперь он стал указывать на пол, он сохранил в себе свойства просто одушевлённого рода.

Поэтому в современном русском языке мужской род в одних случаях указывает на мужской пол, а в других — просто на одушевлённый объект.

Из этого следует, что местоимение ***кто*** не мужского рода, а одушевлённого рода.

И в вашем предложении *«Вы узнаете, **кто** из фавориток так и не **смог** ответить Павлу I взаимностью»* род сказуемого «смог» говорит о том, что это сказуемое описывает действие одушевлённого объекта, а не именно мужчины.

Такая же ситуация, например, и с названиями профессией (инженер, врач, электрик) и т.п., словами, которые не означают именно мужчин, а одушевлённые объекты.

Answer (score 0):

У не безличных глаголов(«кто» не может грамматически относится к безличным), по параметру род, может быть  только три положения: мужской, средний и женский. Словом «кто» обозначают только мужчин или женщин, так что положение среднего рода невозможно. Когда задают вопрос со словом «кто», то зачастую совокупность возможных вариантов неоднородна по полу, но, конструируя такое предложение, вы обязаны ставить глагол в одно из двух положений по параметру род, так как у глаголов в русском языке нет общего или неизвестного рода. Было два возможных варианта, и устоялся вариант с мужским родом.